# Partition using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

Here is my problem, I have a query result set that looks like this:

```
id_1  - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates  
id_2  - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates
id_3  - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_4  - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_5  - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates
id_6  - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_7  - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_8  - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_9  - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_10 - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates
id_11 - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_12 - 1 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_13 - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates 
id_14 - 0 - datetime - gps coordinates
```

This, obviusly returns a list, but I would like to have the sets with value 1 in the second column kept in a list of lists, where each set of lists is one that previously had a 0.
It would look something like this:

```
List1: [id_3], [...] , [id_6]
List2: [id_11], [...], [id_12]
```

I dont know the number of elements with 0 or 1 so this has to be generic in that sense

I'm using C# 4.5, and was thinking of using Linq to do this, instead of the old fashioned foreach.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are something builtin in the framework but you can create an extention method for it :

```
public static class LinqHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<Item>> Partition(this IEnumerable<Item> source, Func<Item, bool> selector)
    {
        List<Item> currentList = new List<Item>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (selector(item))
            {
                currentList.Add(item);
            }
            else if (currentList.Count != 0)
            {
                yield return currentList;
                currentList = new List<Item>();
            }
        }

        if (currentList.Count != 0)
        {
            yield return currentList;
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Val { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Item>(){
        new Item{ Id = 1, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 2, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 3, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 4, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 5, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 6, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 7, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 8, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 9, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 10, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 11, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 12, Val = 1 },
        new Item{ Id = 13, Val = 0 },
        new Item{ Id = 14, Val = 0 },
    };

    var result = list.Partition(i => i.Val == 1).Where(i => true).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `.Where(i => true)`?

Comment: To show that you can continue with other linq operator

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to avoid foreach, here's a way to do it with LINQ's Aggregate extension.

Given the following class:

```
public class SomeType 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Val {get;set;}
}
```

and having generated the following items:

```
var items = new List<SomeType>();
for(var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) 
{
    var val = 0;
    if((3 <= i && i <= 6) || (11 <= i && i <= 12))
        val = 1;
    items.Add(new SomeType { Id = i, Val = val});
}
```

You can get the List of Lists of items with a value of 1 like so:

```
var grouped = items.Aggregate(new List<List<SomeType>>() { new List<SomeType>() },
    (acc,elem) => 
    { 
        if(elem.Val == 0 && acc.Last().Count != 0)  
            acc.Add(new List<SomeType>());
        else if(elem.Val == 1)
            acc.Last().Add(elem);
        return acc;
    }, acc => acc.Where(x => x.Count != 0));

int groupNum = 1;
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group {groupNum++}");
    foreach (var item in group)
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id} - {item.Val}");
}

/* output:
Group 1
3 - 1
4 - 1
5 - 1
6 - 1
Group 2
11 - 1
12 - 1
*/
```

This assumes that it's okay to add entries with the 1 value before a 0 value has occurred, and I'm not sure that's it's especially more readable than using a foreach, and you would likely be better off implementing an extension method that would likely use foreach anyways.

Comment: I never think to use the Aggregate operator. Thx for the reminder. I think your answer is closer to the question than mine.

Comment: @Kalten Aggregate is pretty powerful, to the point that you can implement most other LINQ operations in the terms of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySPDPK);

```
var prev = 0;
List<int> bag = null;
var result = new List<List<int>>();

foreach(var item in list)
{
    if(item.Val == 1)
    {
        if(prev == 0)
        {
            if(bag != null)
                result.Add(bag);
            bag = new List<int>();
        }                       
        bag.Add(item.Id);
    }
    prev = item.Val;
}
if(bag != null)
    result.Add(bag);

result.ForEach(x => {           
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", x));
});
//3, 4, 5, 6
//11, 12
```